# How to arrange image and text side by side?

Tags: beamer

I am working on image and text(description). I need to arrange image and text side by side but in beamer class. It is normal article with a4 size paper. How can i implement it?

Comment: Use wrapfig.sty file

Comment: So, are you using the `beamer` class, or not?

Comment: Yes check the Answer i send

Comment: As your question is a little ambiguous, you can help us a lot by including a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: This question has an answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9464/beamer-text-and-image-on-the-same-slide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate some text

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[10]{r}[0pt]{4cm}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{fig}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[2]

\newpage

\begin{wrapfigure}[10]{l}[0pt]{4cm}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{fig}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

in `article.cls` file also it will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate some text

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[10]{r}[0pt]{4cm}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{fig}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[2]

\newpage

\begin{wrapfigure}[10]{l}[0pt]{4cm}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{fig}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I m using below code and getting image is up and text (in my case itemlist is below). Just to give more info, i need to use my image and text in one mdframed.

Comment: See inside wrapfig.sty, there is more information about wrapfigure coding.

Comment: Hi, I implemented but text is not fully formatted.