# Itemized list side by side with a figure

Tags: beamer

I am trying to create a slide: on the left is an itemized list, on the right is a figure.
It seems I can use `tabular` in beamer, however, the following code doesn't work - it complains about extra \frame. I also tried `fragile` option, but no avail. Can someone help?

```
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{ll}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item test 1
        \item test 2
    \end{itemize}

    & \includegraphics{demo}

\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not using `columns`?

Comment: Duplicate of [Beamer text and image on the same slide](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9464/2693).

Comment: thanks, I didn't google out that answer, my bad