# Picture on the right of the title slide

Tags: beamer

I am trying to create a title slide where the title/author/affiliation/etc is left aligned but in the right hand side there will be a picture ranging from the very top to the bottom. Does anybody know how to do it? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! I think your question is related to this [Beamer text and image on the same slide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9464/124842)

Comment: Simply typeset a page with all information using boxes/`minipage`. I personally do not consider creating a general template of title and using it only one time very time-efficient.

Comment: Have a look at this theme: http://www.drbunsen.org/designing-a-beamer-template-theme/ maybe you can borrow some code there

Answer (score 2):

A quick way is to use `columns`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\title{title}
\institute{inse}
\author{author}
\date{2017}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \begin{columns}[c]
        \begin{column}{.7\textwidth}
            \titlepage
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=\textheight]{example-image}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]