# Identifying the exact place of an image in the beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics

I have write the code of an slide in tex;
the text is shown above the image 
and the image is shown below the text.

> What should I do; such that Image is in the left and the text in right?

---

```
begin{frame}‎
‎\frametitle{History}‎
The problem was first asked 200 years ago.
‎\begin{center}‎
‎\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Image01}‎
‎\end{center}‎
‎\end{frame}‎
```

This code shows the text at top and shows the image in the bottom of the text.

> What should I do to show the text in the right and image in the left?

Comment: `\includegraphics` is positioned using _exactly_ the same logic as a letter such as `x`. If you use `xy` it comes out with x first and if you use `yx` then it comes last.  As with letters if it is one above the other then you have a linebreak or new paragraph (eg blank line)between them.

Comment: Does it help?
 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9464/beamer-text-and-image-on-the-same-slide?rq=1

Comment: Please start to make [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for your questions.

Comment: @samcarter; Yes you are right; so I have added some sample codes I have used.

Comment: @samcarter ; My dear samcarter, I believe that this is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @Famke This is how I understood your question. Can you please clarify what layout your slide should have? Maybe draw a sketch?

Comment: @samcarter ;That code shows the text at top and shows the image in the bottom of the text. I want a code that shows the image in the left and the text in the right of the image.

Comment: @Famke https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9468/36296 shows you how to place image and text side by side.